# typo3: what is the fast way to find which page has certain extension

Tags: typo3

I want to find which page has installed this extension: `jc_register`, I can check every page, but it takes too much time since there are many pages, so I wonder if there is any fast way to find it instead of checking every page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you mean you want to find a content record of type "Insert Plugin" set to a particular extension, you can use "Admin tools".

1. Open "Admin Tools -> DB check".
2. Select "Full search" from the drop-down list.
3. Select "Advanced query".
4. Tick "Use formatted strings, labels and dates instead of original values for results". This will give you page titles in the results when `pid` is displayed.
5. Set the query so that it finds your plugin and lists the page IDs (which means that the "Select fields" must contain `pid`).

[image]

**Note**: Tested in **TYPO3 4.5 LTS** and might not work in later versions.

Answer (score 2):

Hi the extension name is located in "tt_content.list_type" field. So something like this should help you:

```
SELECT tt_content.pid,pages.title
FROM tt_content JOIN pages ON tt_content.pid = pages.uid
WHERE tt_content.list_type LIKE '%register%'
ORDER BY tt_content.uid DESC
```

gl

Comment: Note that this is what "Admin Tools -> DB check" does. It builds a query like this while giving you a select box of plugins that can be on the page. Also note that you should include `tt_content.CType = 'list'` in the query as otherwise you might get records that were of content type "Insert Plugin" with that particular plugin set but were later changed to a different content type (`list_type` is not erased in such case).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do it more often, you might consider the extension backendtools: http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/backendtools

It offers an extension listing with search functionality and links to the according page.